# Setting values for Dataframe abnormally slow but fast on a copy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a tiny Pandas DataFrame with one column and ~300 rows. Now I would like to set that value for a given row to a new value, i.e.

```
df.loc[row_idx, colname] = new_value
```

The problem is, that for some reason this operation takes ~2s. However, when I make a copy of the dataframe and run the same operation on the copy

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2.loc[row_idx, colname] = new_value
```

the operation only takes ~0.001s.
I have thought, that maybe a property of the original dataframe makes selection very slow. `DataFrame.copy` generates a deep copy though, so its indices are also copied to df2.

Unfortunately I can't provide a minimal working example, since the DataFrame is essentially given to me by library code that I do not have control over.

I would appreciate any suggestions what the issue might be!

Thanks

Edit: I'm using Pandas version 0.19.1

Comment: How are you measuring this `execution time`? if you're using the `time` package, it can be unreliable, because other processes working in the background in your system can hamper the performance causing delays.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `time.time()`. However if I make a copy and then only set the values on the copy the execution time of the entire code reduces significantly. For some reason it really takes absurdly long to set the values on the original dataframe.